# Problema DNS Azure Windows

Tags: microsoft-azure, dns

Eu sou novo no ramo de configuração de vps etc..

Estava testando algumas coisas na vps azure windowse alterei o DNS para 127.0.0.1 na rede e perdi a conexão remota na hora tenho arquivos importantes e muitas coisas que ja fiz lá, tem como eu voltar para dns padrão no powershell azure ou logar na vps novamente?

Agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Só resetei a vps volto a funcionar obrigado.

Comment: Mova seu comentário para a resposta e marque sua pergunta como respondida.